# Joining multiple tables but not all

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

I'm wanting to join the results based on Table1 *(`product`)* and Table3 *(`system_type`)*. Whereas Table2 *(`system_cat`)* doesn't include the column I want to join. **How can I join Table1 and Table2, but only join Table1 and Table3 in one statement?**

Current non-joined version:

```
 SELECT * FROM product LEFT JOIN system_cat USING (cat_id) LEFT JOIN system_type USING (type_id) WHERE system_furniture_check = 0 AND cat_id = :c ORDER BY sortorder
```

Joined non-working version (attempt 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM product LEFT JOIN system_cat USING (cat_id) LEFT JOIN system_type USING (type_id) WHERE system_furniture_check = 0 AND cat_id = :c ORDER BY sortorder
```

Alternative joined non-working version (attempt 2):

```
SELECT product.*, system_cat.*, system_type.* 
FROM product 
JOIN system_cat 
ON system_cat.cat_id = product.cat_id 
JOIN system_type 
ON system_type.type_id = product.type_id 
WHERE system_furniture_check = 0 AND cat_id = :c ORDER BY sortorder
```

The error:

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'cat_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tables:

- product – type_id, cat_id
- system_cat – cat_id
- system_type – type_id, cat_id

Comment: You need to add a table name (or alias) before `cat_id` in your where clause

Comment: WHat the error says is that you have to specify the table of `cat_id`. Look where you're using `cat_id` and take care of adding a table and i'll work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a table name (or alias) before cat_id in your where clause.
Use the modified query below, replacing ???? with the tablename that you want to use.

```
SELECT product.*, system_cat.*, system_type.* 
FROM product 
JOIN system_cat USING (cat_id)
JOIN system_type USING (type_id)
WHERE system_furniture_check = 0 
AND ????.cat_id = :c 
ORDER BY sortorder
```

Its also OK to use 'USING' if the columns you are matching on are the same name.

Comment: Although @Madhivana got there first, I do like the simplicity behind this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As it says you need to prefix table qualifier. Try this. Also do not use *, just type out the required columns

```
SELECT product.*, system_cat.*, system_type.* 
FROM product 
JOIN system_cat 
ON system_cat.cat_id = product.cat_id 
JOIN system_type 
ON system_type.type_id = product.type_id 
WHERE system_furniture_check = 0 AND system_cat.cat_id = :c ORDER BY sortorder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are missing the qualifier for the tables:

```
SELECT p, sc, st 
FROM product p
INNER JOIN system_cat sc
ON sc.cat_id = p.cat_id
INNER JOIN system_type st
ON st.type_id = p.type_id 
WHERE system_furniture_check = 0 AND sc.cat_id = :c ORDER BY sortorder;
```